# How do I solve $E=\frac{(I\times e^{(-\sigma\times R)})}{R^2}$ for $R$?

Tags: functions

> How do I solve $E=\frac{(I\times e^{(-\sigma\times R)})}{R^2}$ for $R$?

I'd like to express this as a function of R, but if it can be done, it eludes me.

I'm thoroughly stuck, so I'd like to ask for some help.

What I've done so far just muddies the waters- I've tried using the natural log to tease apart everything, but it hasn't helped me getting any closer to a solution in terms of $R$.

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: The only way to be able to express this in terms of R is with the Lambert W function (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), but not sure that will help you get what you want very much

Comment: Thanks, was afraid of that.

Answer (score 0):

As Brneton commented, the only analytical solution is given in terms of Lambert function.

To make the problem looking simpler, let $-\sigma R=x$ and $k=\frac{E}{I \sigma ^2}$ to make the equation
$$e^x=k x^2$$ the solutions of which being
$$x_\pm=-2W\left(\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{2k}}\right)$$ You must take care that, in the real domain $W(t)$ is real valued if $t \geq -\frac 1e$. If you do not access Lambert function, you can have estimates using the expansions provided in the Wikipedia page.

Otherwise, only numerical methods could give the solution.

Comment: Claude- thanks! I will study this this evening. Appreciate the help.

Comment: @NonceDrive. It is really worth to look at this function. It is just fantastic. Try to remember that any equation which can write or rewrite as $A+B x+C \log(D+Ex)=0$ has solutions in terms of Lambert function. Here, on MSE, just search for *Lambert* : 2728 entries. Enjoy & cherrs :-)

Comment: Claude - Thanks again, it seems really useful. Was entirely unaware of it. A pity they don't seem to have a native function for in Google sheets. :)